# How is this code creating a numeric "dartboard"?

Tags: python

I have been attempting to learn Python for a couple months now.
I've been doing practice exercises on edabit.com and have consistently been grasping the "Hard" and "Very Hard" tasks. I figured I'd give an "Expert" problem a shot just to see what I'd be getting into.
I was presented a task to create a square "dartboard" out of a list of integers by only being given the length.

Exercise can be found here:
https://edabit.com/challenge/Kv8DMmwfuKTLyZD5E

**Output should look like this:**

```
make_dartboard(8) ➞ [
  11111111,
  12222221,
  12333321,
  12344321,
  12344321,
  12333321,
  12222221,
  11111111
]
```

As expected, I was truly stumped. Treating it as a learning exercise I went ahead an looked at other users' solutions and came across the following code:

**Code in Question:**

```
def make_dartboard(n):
    row, top = 0, []
    for i in range(n, 0, -2):
        row += int('{:0^{}}'.format('1'*i, n))
        top.append(row)
    bottom = top[::-1][1:] if n%2 else top[::-1]
    return top + bottom
```

I've looked this over for over an hour now but can't quite discern HOW this code is functioning. I'll admit that there are countless Python concepts, functions, and syntax I still don't understand, but I really want to (for instance, the .format() is still a brand new function for me and still don't fully understand it).

**Would someone be so kind to break down what exactly is happening in this code?** What really is tripping me up are rows 4 and 6.

I appreciate any time you are willing to give me and am grateful you even took the time to read through this.

*I want to give credit to edabit users Joshua Señoron and zatoichi49 for creating and solving the problem respectively.

Comment: This question might fit at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! 
I actually tried to ask a separate question to that community but they closed it because I didn’t write the code... Is there a good community to ask about existing code trying to understand what it’s doing? Sometimes Google turns up zilch when trying to understand certain concepts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we are making a size(5) dartboard, the output should be:

```
>>> make_dartboard(5)
[11111, 12221, 12321, 12221, 11111]
```

Let's look at the code line by line, :

`for i in range(n, 0, -2):`  -> `for i in [5, 3, 1]`

`row += int('{:0^{}}'.format('1'*i, n))`

[`^ in string formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) means to:

> Forces the field to be centred within the available space.

`'{:0^{}}'.format('1'*i, n))`, it gives n-length string with `i` numbers of `'1'` in center fills with `'0'` outside. More on [`string.format()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486173/how-is-this-python-code-creating-a-numeric-dartboard).

> 1. with, `i = 5` and `n = 5`, it gives '11111'.
> 2. with, `i = 3` and `n = 5`, it gives '01110'
> 3. with, `i = 1` and `n = 5`, it gives '00100'

Within the forloop, `row` equals to its cumulative sum in `int` (so it can be added up):

> 1. with, `i = 5` and `n = 5`, `row` -> 11111
> 2. with, `i = 3` and `n = 5`, `row` -> 12221
> 3. with, `i = 1` and `n = 5`, `row` -> 12321

The `row`s are append to `top` in order, the rest of the code is to create the same list in reverse order to `bottom`. Lastly, return the concatenated list of `top` and `bottom`

`bottom = top[::-1][1:] if n%2 else top[::-1] #code [::-1] reverses the list`
`bottom` copies the `top` list from bottom to top. If `n` is even, it copies from the very bottom. If `n` is odd, as you may notice, there is one unique centre `row` which needs to be skipped when concat `bottom` to `top`.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This was unbelievably helpful, thank you for taking the time to break this down for me.

Comment: @AustinEckel Happy to help, my friend. I'd be great to upvote and accept my answer if you found it helpful. Happy coding!